# create self packed ApRun image includex libonnxruntime(gpu) with gpu support

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, onnxruntime, appimage

I am creating App image with linuxdeployqt and also linuxdeploy . all looks fine .

I transferred the appimage to another ubuntu with gpu its running withour error but on the cpu not on the gpu .No matter what I cant run the app on the gpu on the new machine.

How I can find the problem ? is it the libonnxruntime causing the error ? how I can determine the missing part to run on gpu ?

Is there any specific issu for these ?